# vim taglist: show class members as a respective class tag subtree

Tags: vim, taglist

I'm new with vim's taglist plugin and have a question regarding display style of classes and members within taglist window. Taglist displays them as two separate lists: one for classes and one for class members. However I would like class members to be displayed as a subtree of a respective class tag. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't. But another plugin, [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/), was created specifically for that.